# How to find the matrix that spans Linear space defined below?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a number, say $n$, of $k\times j$ matrices $A_i$ and I need to find a matrix whose columns span the space defined as below
$$\mathcal{J^*}=\{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^j:A_i\alpha=0\,\forall i \text{ with } i=1,2,\ldots,n\}.$$
Now, if $n=1$, then $\mathcal{J}^*$ coincides with the null space of $A_1$. I am trying to figure out if this problem has a solution when $i>1$. I have thought about summing the $A_i$'s and then calculating the matrix that spans the kernel of $\sum_i^nA_i$. I have understood that calculating the matrix that spans the kernel of the sum of the matrices $A_i$ does not work.

Do you have any hints? Is there a smart way to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: I changed $(k\,x\,j)$ to $k\times j$.  That is standard. ${}\quad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each matrix equation $A_i \alpha = 0$ consists of $k$ linear equations. Thus, the system $A_1 \alpha = A_2 \alpha = \ldots = A_n \alpha = 0$ consists of $nk$ linear equations for $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}^j_{\mathrm{col}}$. If you want to write them in matrix form, you can construct a large block matrix $A \in M_{(nk) \times j}(\mathbb{F})$ from the $A_i$:

$$ A = \left( \begin{array}{c} A_1 \\ \hline \vdots \\ \hline A_n \end{array} \right). $$

Then the matrix you are looking for can be constructed by finding a basis for $\ker(A)$ (using Gaussian elimination for example) and choosing the basis vectors to form the columns of the matrix.

Comment: What do you mean with $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_{\text{col}}^j$?

Comment: I wrote the answer for a general field as it doesn't matter whether you do it over the real numbers or over an arbitrary field. The notation $\mathbb{F}^j_{\mathrm{col}}$ is just to remind you that $\alpha$ is a $j \times 1$ column vector.